# How to fix SQL Server and cast and replace query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was past a request to replace in a table called BODYCONTENT for the BODY column and references to old server with new server.

The vendor sent the following SQL, but it failed. Any ideas on this?

```
update BODYCONTENT  
set BODY = replace(CAST(BODY AS nvarchar(MAX), 'https://oldserver.com', 'https://newserver.com');
```

Error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 23
>   Incorrect syntax near ','

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a right parenthesis in the CAST before the comma

```
update BODYCONTENT 
SET BODY = replace(CAST(BODY AS nvarchar(MAX)), 'https://oldserver.com', 'https://newserver.com');
```